# PHP sessions and cookies

Tags: php, session, cookies

We have a PHP site that our users as well as clients use. Our login system works fine on all browsers.

Recently we came across a client who was unable to login into the system. We also tested the same on the clients side and failed to find a solution.

When a client logs in a cookie tk_client_admin is created in the browser, this is created correctly on all browsers at our side, but the same fails to create in the clients browser both IE and Chrome. On FF is works both sides.

This issues seems to be happening only on IE and Chrome and for certain clients only, what could be the problem?

Comment: Can you confirm that cookies are enabled on those machines?

Comment: Can the client access other cookie based sites? If so then you have a problem and if not then they have a problem.

Comment: Let's see the code creating the cookie

Comment: do they have any antivirus or software that prevents cookies or such ? do they have a different installation of windows that might have rules to prevent writes on certain places ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you provided, it sounds like there is some sort of network wide restriction placed on IE and Chrome. Maybe they're not permitted to created cookies.

Have you tried using the same browsers (IE and Chrome) on their machines to connect to other sites that also require cookies?

Comment: I am using the codeigniter framework, so the db_session class creates the cookie the usual way.

 setcookie($this->session_data_cookie, $cookie_data, $cookie_expiry, $this->CI->config->item('cookie_path'), $this->CI->config->item('cookie_domain'), $this->session_secure, $this->session_http_only);

The client has Maccafe antivirus installed